# boost::unordered_map::find produces different results depending on compiler optimization level while boost::unordered_map::insert produces the same

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compiler-optimization

Using gcc 4.8.1 and libboost 1.53 I get different results depending on the optimization levels I use for compiling my code.
As part of a larger program the function `insertValues` is executed twice for the same `a`, `key` and `value`:

```
/* Complex classes */
class A { /*....*/ }
class Value { /*.....*/ }
class SortedVector : public std::vector<T> { /*.....*/ }

/* Hash for the key */
struct KeyHash : std::unary_function<Key, size_t> {
    size_t operator()(Key const& x) const {
        size_t hash = x.get<0>();
        SortedVector<int>* xNumbers = x.get<2>();
        if(xNumbers != NULL) {
            BOOST_FOREACH(int num, *xNumbers) {
                MurmurHash3_x86_32(&num, sizeof(size_t), hash, &hash);
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }
};

/* Equals for the key */
struct KeyEqual : std::binary_function<Key, Key, bool> {
    size_t operator()(Key const& x, Key const& y) const {
        if(x.get<0>() != y.get<0>() || fabs(x.get<1>() - y.get<1>()) > 0.00001 || x.get<3>() != y.get<3>()) {
            return false;
        }

        SortedVector<int>* xNumbers = x.get<2>();
        SortedVector<int>* yNumbers = y.get<2>();
        if(xNumbers == yNumbers) {
            return true;
        }

        if(xNumbers == NULL || yNumbers == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        if(xNumbers->size() != yNumbers->size()) {
            return false;
        }
        return std::equal(xNumbers->begin(), xNumbers->end(), yNumbers->begin());
    }
};

/* typedefs */
typedef boost::tuple<int, double, SortedVector<int>*, int> Key;
typedef boost::unordered_map<A, boost::unordered_map<Key, Value*, KeyHash, KeyEqual>, A::Hash, A::Equal> Map;

/* code that shows the problem */
void insertValues(A a, Key key, Value* value) {
    Map::iterator iter = map->find(a);
    if (iter == map->end()) {
        iter = map.insert(std::make_pair(a, Map::value_type::second_type())).first;
    }

    Map::value_type::second_type::iterator keyIter = iter->second.find(key);

    if (keyIter == iter->second.end()) {
        iter->second.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
    }
}
```

Compiled with `-O2` the `keyIter` is always equal to `iter->second.end()`, indicating that the `key, value` pair is not in the map. However, when run the second time, the `insert` does not insert the pair.
After consulting the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) for `insert` and `find` I come to the conclusion, that while `find` does not find the pair, `insert` finds it and rejects insertion.

Compiled with `-O1` the code works as expected.

Does anyone have an insight, why `find` might produce different results with `-O1` and `-O2`? Or why the lookup results of `find` and `insert` can differ?

The hashes make use of MurmurHash3_x86_32 from [MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3).
The system is an OpenSuse x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: What is A, Key and Value? A compilable example would help very much.

Comment: This smells like undefined behavior, can you show us your hash and equal methods to start with?

Comment: Hash and equality operations will be crucial. A SSCCE would be required to spot any UB in surrounding code

Comment: I have updated the code to include the types of a, key and value and the `Hash` and `Equal` functions for Key. However, why should the hash-function work for insert but not for find? I cannot reproduce the problem in a minimum working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely source of the bug is your call to the hash function:

```
        BOOST_FOREACH(int num, *xNumbers) {
            MurmurHash3_x86_32(&num, sizeof(size_t), hash, &hash);
        }
```

You're using OpenSuse x86_64 GNU/Linux, which is an LP64 platform, so `int` is 32 bits while `size_t` (and `long`) is 64 bits wide. In [the implementation of `MurmurHash3_x86_32`](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/branches/chandlerc_dev/MurmurHash3.cpp#94) the `key` is accessed bytewise and also by 32-bit block (`uint32_t`). This is OK, as [it's allowed to alias signed and unsigned variants of the same integral type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) (and any trivially copyable type bytewise), and `uint32_t` must be `unsigned int` as there are no other fundamental unsigned 32-bit integral types on x86_64 Linux.

However, there are two bugs in this code. First, the `len` parameter should be the size of the `key`, but `sizeof(size_t)` is 8 on your platform, whereas `int num` is 4 bytes in size. This means that the hash function will read an undefined memory location (`&num + 1`), and an optimizing compiler is free to provide any value for this read or cause other undefined behavior.

Second, you supply `&hash` as the `out` parameter. But `MurmurHash3_x86_32` writes to `*out` as `uint32_t`, and `size_t` cannot alias `uint32_t` as the two types are distinct arithmetic types and not signed/unsigned variants. This means that the write to `hash` has undefined behavior and an optimizing compiler is free to ignore this write or cause other undefined behavior.

Something like this would be more correct:

```
        std::uint32_t result;
        MurmurHash3_x86_32(xNumbers->data(),
            sizeof(*xNumbers->data()) * xNumbers->size(),
            hash, &result);
        hash ^= (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(hash) ^ result);
```

Note that contrary to your code this supplies all the `xNumbers` in a single call to the hash function. This is guaranteed to work as `vector` stores its elements contiguously, and is closer to how the hash function is intended to be used; it is not designed to be called repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. However, I had to change `sizeof(xNumbers->data())` to `sizeof(int)` to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `fabs(x.get<1>() - y.get<1>()) > 0.00001` can make different objects look the same to the container. You should just say `x.get<1>() != y.get<1>()`.

Comment: If the difference in that number is so small, then the objects should be treated equally. I avoid `!=` for floating point variables, since they are hardly ever really equal due to the way they are represented.

Comment: It's a contract violation for objects with distinct hashes to compare equal. Also, it breaks transitivity of equality (`0.000011 == 0.000017 && 0.000017 == 0.000024` but `0.000011 != 0.000024`). But I don't think that's the bug here.